# Is it possible to loop through a C# Class object?

Tags: c#

I have a C# class that I want to loop through the properties as a key/value pair but don't know how.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
Foreach (classobjectproperty prop in classobjectname)
{
    if (prop.name == "somename")
        //do something cool with prop.value
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup:

```
Type type = typeof(Form); // Or use Type.GetType, etc
foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
{
    // Do stuff with property
}
```

This won't give them as key/value pairs, but you can get all kinds of information from a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx).

Note that this will only give public properties. For non-public ones, you'd want to use the overload which takes a `BindingFlags`. If you *really* want just name/value pairs for instance properties of a particular instance, you could do something like:

```
var query = foo.GetType()
               .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                              BindingFlags.Instance)
               // Ignore indexers for simplicity
               .Where(prop => !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any())
               .Select(prop => new { Name = prop.Name,
                                     Value = prop.GetValue(foo, null) });

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Name, pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c) - although that restricts to public properies the approach should work for you to get them all.