# Iterate through properties and values of an object returned via a linq query on a domain model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, telerik-open-access

I have a custom entity in a relational database that I have mapped to the CLR via a domain model. So by using the following statement, I can pull in an entity from my database into memory via a LINQ query on the domain model, like so;

```
var inspection = (from i in dbContext.New_testinspectionExtensionBases
              where i.New_testinspectionId == currentInspection   
              select i).First();
```

There are properties/fields on this entity that I need access to, I need to be able to determine the property/field name as well as it's value. I want to loop through these items in memory, and write out their names and values to the console.

I tried using this approach, but couldn't figure out how to correct the syntax (Nor am I sure that GetProperties is the correct method to use, GetFields wasn't returning anything for some reason so I assumed this was the way to go) but it doesn't really matter since all i need is read access to the value;

```
var inspectionReportFields = inspection.GetType().GetProperties(); 
// I called this inspectionReportfields because the entity properties correspond to 
// form/report fields I'm generating from this data.

foreach (var reportField in inspectionReportFields)
{
    var value = reportField.GetValue();
    Console.WriteLine(reportField.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Is there an easier way to get the property/field value when utilizing a domain model like EF or openaccess? If not, am I going about it the right way? And lastly, if so, how do I fix the syntax in the value variable declaration?

Here are some sample fields/properties from the code generated by the domain model, for reference;

```
    private int? _new_systemGauges;
    public virtual int? New_systemGauges 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this._new_systemGauges;
        }
        set
        {
            this._new_systemGauges = value;
        }
    }

    private int? _new_systemAlarm ;
    public virtual int? New_systemAlarm 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this._new_systemAlarm;
        }
        set
        {
            this._new_systemAlarm = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to define a general-purpose way to "dump" an object without knowing anything about its structure. If so, then you are going about things the correct way. You use reflection (`GetType()` and the associated `Type` class methods) to inspect the object and return its information.

The reason `GetFields()` didn't return anything is that you likely did not supply the right binding flags. In particular, if you call the overload that doesn't take any parameters, you only get back `public` fields; if you want private fields you need to ask for them specifically.

In your case, `GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)` would give you back the `_new_systemGauges` and `_new_systemAlarm` fields, while GetProperties() would give you back the `New_systemAlarm` and `New_systemAlarm` properties.

The other key element you missed is that the data you are getting back is the **type** metadata; it defines the structure of the `class`, and not any particular instance. If you want to know what the value of a property for a specific instance is, you need to ask for that:

```
foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

One you have one of the `PropertyInfo` elements from the type's metadata, you can ask for that property value on any instance of that type. It doesn't have to be the same instance that you originally used. For example:

```
var objs = somelist.Where(x => x.Id == 1);
foreach (var prop in objs.First().GetType().GetProperties())
{
  int x = 0;
  foreach (var obj in objs)
  {        
    if (prop.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Int32"))
    {
      int val = (int)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
      Console.WriteLine("Obj #{0}: {1} = 0x{2:x8}", x++, prop.Name, val);
    }
    else if (prop.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Decimal"))
    {
      int val = (decimal)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
      Console.WriteLine("Obj #{0}: {1} = {2:c2}", x++, prop.Name, val);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Obj #{0}: {1} = '{2}'", x++, prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null));
    }
  }
}
```

Technically you should check the result of `GetIndexParameters` to see if a property is indexed or not; the `null` parameter to `GetValue` is actually an array of index values.

To convert the value you get back you can either use typecasts, or if you want to be a bit more flexible, use the Convert class's methods. The difference is, for example, if you have a `short` property, `GetValue()` will return a boxed short, which you cannot then typecast as an `int`; you have to unbox it to a `short` first. Using `Convert.ToInt32()` will perform all of the needed steps to get an `int` value out of any property that is *convertible to* an integer.

Converting between reference types is easier since you can just use `is` and `as` for that; those work just like you'd expect with "reflected" property values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response, it helped my understanding greatly!

Comment: When i'm using GetValue(inspection, null) and I try to compare that value in an if statement I run into type issues (comparing an object to an int) so I tried to unbox the value from the object and compare it to my int but it's giving me the null reference exception. I'm still learning, so i'm not sure what I need to do in order to correct the error. If i just pull in this info into a console window, it isn't null - as it does show the value. But when i go to use it in an if statement, it shows null in the debugger and throws the exception

Comment: Or is there any way to return only the value of the int held within the object being returned, instead of the object itself

Comment: Ok, I re-read my original reply to that comment and it made no sense so lemme try again. You absolutely should be able to typecast the return value from an integer property to an actual integer; at worst you ought to get an invalid typecast exception, not a null value. I'd have to see the code you're using to see why you get nulls back. I've edited my answer to show an example of how the typecast would work.

Answer (score 2):

`GetProperties` indeed is the correct method.

To get rid of the compiler error, change your code to this:

```
var value = reportField.GetValue(inspection, null);
```

You need to pass the instance from which you want to obtain the value, as a `PropertyInfo` object is not bound to any specific class instance.

---

Please consider following the standard .NET naming rules.

This would lead to the following:

`NewSystemAlarm` instead of `New_systemAlarm`
`newSystemAlarm` or `_newSystemAlarm` instead of `_new_systemAlarm`
`NewTestInspectionExtensionBases` instead of `New_testinspectionExtensionBases`
`NewTestInspectionId` instead of `New_testinspectionId`

Comment: This is basically the answer I needed, but thanks to the above detailed post I also have a better understanding so that is why I marked it as the answer (since I can't mark both apparently). The naming schema is out of my control unfortunately, it's a microsoft product that I'm working with :). Thanks Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenAccess you always have the complete information about your model classes at your disposal. The information there is retrieved from your mapping which means that you needn't reflect over your classes (no overhead).

Just browse trough context.Metadata.PersistentTypes for all of your classes mapping information.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking but wasn't sure where to look. Thanks very much!