# Hidden fields for all model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to create hidden fields for all model public properties?

I look for something like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(t => t)
```

Comment: what is the reason you want to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop Through An Objects Properties In C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want this to happen automatically, you will need to use reflection.

Comment: @Shyju I want to display confirmation screen with only few of model properties and when user clicks Save post all model properties to action method.

Comment: I decided to use Reflection with Hidden helper method, Thx for comments.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the reason you want to do this is to get the other property values when you update your entity record in an Edit screen. you may be editing a few properties (and only those are in your form) and you may be getting `null` for all other properties which was not in the form.

What you should be doing is,Keep only the PostID property in a hidden field in your form and In your `HttpPost` action method, Read the entity and update only those properties which was sent from the form and save it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Post model)
{
  var existingPost=repositary.GetPost(model.PostID);

  //Set only the properties posted from form to the existingPost entity
  existingPost.Title=model.Title;

  var result= repositary.SavePost(existingPost);
  return RedirectToAction("PostSaved",new {@id=model.PostID});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ for displaying confirmation window. Specify form submit on Ok button click. 
See example below:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Post", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new {@id = "frmPost" , enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}

<div id="dialog">Some confirmation</div>        

<script>
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $("#frmPost").submit();
                $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).close();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```