# C#ception - DateTime equals should be equals be it's not

Tags: c#

I was using the [Jon Skeet solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957809/2307070) to compare the properties of two complex objects when something weird happened: Those two dates, which *looks* the same, was failed at the `!object.Equals(firstValue, secondValue)` test. Grabbing my debugger, I debugged and it seems that the two objects are the very same:

[image]

Then I look in the details (pressing the <kbd>+</kbd>) and found this:

[image]

Could this be causing the `Equals()` to fails? Or are my eyes shitty and the difference is visible, elsewhere?

Comment: No, a `DateTime` has a `Date` property which returns the `DateTime` without time(so midnight), that `DateTime` of course also has a `Date` property and so on.

Comment: @TimSchmelter then why is the equals failing?

Comment: You have provided too less informations to find the reason. I dont know the class definition and i don't  see  instances. Also, i don't like the reflection approach. Reflection should be the very last resort.

Comment: @TimSchmelter please, tell me what you need, I'll be very glad to add information to unstuck myself

Comment: I chose to close this question as a duplicate because you're comparing arrays, not instances of `DateTime`. Arrays are compared by reference, not by the values of their items.

Comment: `firstValue` is a one-dimensional **array** of `DateTime`, having length 1. And `secondValue` is _another_ array. If you use `object.Equals(firstValue, secondValue)` you get `false` because they are different array instances, and arrays have reference-type equality semantics. Did you mean to say instead `object.Equals(firstValue[0], secondValue[0])`? That would give `true` because of the value-type semantics of `DateTime`. Also note that `DateTime` overloads the `operator ==`, and for that reason the usual thing to do is `firstValue[0] == secondValue[0]`.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: My crystal ball says that you need to remove `!` from the expression.   Because their equal.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks to point out the **real** issue. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: @Thomas, that's your choice, but it wouldn't hurt to leave the question around I believe -- it may be useful to others.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you mean that I'll get downvote but it'll may help someone else ?

Comment: @Thomas, well, let's not be too pessimistic -- your question has not been downvoted so far, and may never be (we're all human, and posting duplicates happen). On the other hand, the question might very well help someone else later, yes.

Comment: _(removed earlier version of this comment because it contained a fatal typo)_ If you want to compare arrays by entries, you can use `System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(firstArray, seconArray)`. If the arrays are equal in an entry-wise sense, that gives `true` even if those are distinct instances of `Array`.