# ASP.NET MVC C# - Using array values to loop through model fields e.g. model.[Array Value]

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model

I am trying to use array to loop through model fields
`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.[fld])` where fld is in an array
flds see code below. Please let me know how to do this.

```
@model IEnumerable<SchoolAutomationSite.Models.tblClass>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "List Of Classes";
    }

    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New Class", "Create")
    </p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
```

> This is the Array

```
    @{
        string[] DisplayName = { "name", "description", "createdAt", "updatedAt" };
    }


    @foreach (var fld in flds)
    {

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.[fld])
```

> How to do the above line?

```
            </th>
    }
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>

            @foreach (var fld in flds)
            {

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.[flds])
                </td>
            }


            use the above instead off
            ----------
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.createdAt)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.updatedAt)
            </td>

            ----------
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

Comment: the array is "string[] flds" not "string[] DisplayName". So that is not problem

Comment: This just makes your view code less readable, why not just stick with the more verbose code?

Comment: It would be just `@foreach (var fld in flds) { <th>@fld</th> }` - but why do this?

Comment: First I need to get the DisplayNameFor using the array in the headers. Second I need to use the array to get the row values. Also than I can just add any new flds in the array without changing the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a dotNet object to a dictionary and then iterate through the keys collection.  Here's an extension method I've used in the past:

```
    public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Turns object into dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IDictionary<string, TVal> ToDictionary<TVal>(this object o)
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o);
            var d = new Dictionary<string, TVal>();
            foreach (var prop in props.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>())
            {
                var val = prop.GetValue(o);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    d.Add(prop.Name, (TVal)val);
                }
            }
            return d;
        }
        return new Dictionary<string, TVal>();
    }

}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var fields = Model.ToDictionary();
foreach (var key in fields.Keys) {
    <td>
        @fields[key]
    </td>
}
```

or, using your flds array:

```
var fields = Model.ToDictionary();
foreach (var fld in flds) {
    <td>
        @fields[fld]
    </td>
}
```

Comment: You probably want to filter the properties too depending on the model/object you're trying to iterate through...

Comment: I was looking for a simple solution. Also it doesnt really answer the question

Comment: It does provide you with a way to iterate through the properties on a model; isn't that what you wanted?  Once you've got that you can do what you like with the properties/values...

Comment: You could also look at this StackOverflow question for an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c-sharp