# foreach over a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like the following in C#, but I can't figure out how to instantiate any of the container types in place:

```
foreach (string aOrB in new Tuple("A","B"))
{
    fileNames.Add("file" + aOrB + ".png");
}
```

I know the typical way it to create the Tuple/Array/Set container in the surrounding scope.  Is there something better?

Comment: So do you need `List` of strings or `Tuple`? It is two pretty different data structures.

Comment: Do you mean `new List<string>{"A", "B"}`? Or is it a challenge to iterate [over properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/957783/1997232)?

Comment: Or you can also go with just an array. `in new[] {"A", "B"}`

Answer (score 13):

As far as I understand, you want to provide a set of items defined ad-hoc for your loop. You can do this with the array initialization syntax:

```
foreach (string aOrB in new[] { "A", "B" })
{
    fileNames.Add("file" + aOrB + ".png");
}
```

This is already a shortened form of

```
foreach (string aOrB in new string[] { "A", "B" })
{
    fileNames.Add("file" + aOrB + ".png");
}
```

(the long form would be necessary if the compiler could not figure out the array element type from the elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
foreach(string aOrB in new List<string>() { "a", "b" })
{
    fileNames.Add("file" + aOrB + ".png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's more convenient to derive your string list by calling `.Split`, e.g.

```cs
foreach (string aOrB in "A,B".Split(","))
{
    fileNames.Add($"file{aOrB}.png");
}
```