# What's the best way to compare all properties of two objects?

Tags: c#

For example, if I have two objects(same class) that have more than 100 properties , and I'd like to compare if two objects' all properties are identical except "ID" property.

What's the best way to do it?

Okay... Maybe I described not too clear... I only want to compare public properties of two objects, so I think this one pretty much solved my issue.
[Loop Through An Objects Properties In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you sure you mean attributes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You probably mean "properties" or "fields" instead of "attributes". What do you mean by "best"? Easiest to code?

Comment: try Reflection.

Comment: You could override the equals method on the class itself, or create a helper to do such thing

Comment: Yeah,,, It should be comparing properties.

Comment: @austinwernli but do I need to write all properties in the Equal method again? Is there a way that I don't need to list all properties

Comment: @EdPlunkett The best way means the shortest code that I don't need to list all properties again

Comment: @Kai You should probably say that in your question. I don't advise overriding `Equals()`, but do so if you like. The way to do it is to write a method like so: `public bool IsEqualTo(ThisClass r) { foreach (var propInfo in GetType().GetProperties(/*flags*/)) { /* use propInfo to get values from this and r, and compare them. If not "ID" and not equal, return false. */ } }`

Comment: Using reflection is explained in multiple answers in the duplicate.

Comment: Right. Thanks everyone. Reflection solved the issue.